# negate a matching regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, quotes, regex-negation

We want to group characters together which occur between line breaks (`\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`), but ignore line breaks which occur within quotes. Something like this:

```
test = 'hello \r\n you, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", hej\r\nhello, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", "hej\r\ngreat", you?'

match -> hello 
match ->  you, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", hej
match -> hello, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", "hej\r\ngreat", you?
```

We managed to get something working that would fit most of our needs, but it does not ignore line breaks within quotes:

```
In [342]: test = 'hello \r\n you, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", hej\r\nhello, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", "hej\r\ngreat", you?'

In [343]: [r for r in re.finditer(r'([^(\r\n)])+', test)]
Out[343]:
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='hello '>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 28), match=' you, hi, hola, "hei'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(29, 38), match='hei", hej'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(40, 61), match='hello, hi, hola, "hei'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(62, 72), match='hei", "hej'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(74, 86), match='great", you?'>]
```

So we tried a different approach: create a pattern that would find the ones we want to exclude and then try to negate it:

```
In [344]: [r for r in re.finditer(r'(\r\n|\n)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)', test)]
Out[344]:
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 8), match='\r\n'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(38, 40), match='\r\n'>]
```

But we can't figure out how to properly negate it. We are using `re.finditer()` rather than `re.split()` because we want to return a generator.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of task that regex isn't particularly well suited for parsing.  Would you consider using something like `pyparsing` instead?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?:"[^"]*"|.)+', test)`.

Comment: Regular expressions are a bad fit for nesting logic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your solution is actually way nicer than mine ^^'

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `pyparsing` @mgilson, didn't know of it!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that solution works great, only thing is that it leaves `\r` in the matched groups like:

`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='hello \r'>,`

which would need to strip off manually

Comment: @eberbis: Ok, I see. I do not think it is the most efficient regex anyway.

Comment: If http://ideone.com/sqPrPs works better than the other solution I will post.

Comment: I have accepted @Faibbus solution because he accounted for the edge cases and won't return any `\r`, but really appreciated your help @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with `([^"\r\n]*(?:"[^"]+"[^"\r\n]*)*)`.

This way, you will find any string not having a linefeed nor a quote that can be followed by any number of string in quotes.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/MD7Don/2)

```
import re,pprint
test = 'hello \r\n you, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", hej\r\nhello, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", "hej\r\ngreat", you?'
pprint.pprint(re.findall(r'([^\"\r\n]*(?:\"[^\"]+\"[^\"\r\n]*)*)', test))
```

will output:

```
['hello ',
 ' you, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", hej',
 'hello, hi, hola, "hei\nhei", "hej\r\ngreat", you?']
```

Comment: this is great, @Faibbus!!! Pretty much what we needed! 
We only have just found out that for this use case it would stripped the new line:

`'"\r\n" Hello how are you\r\n\r I am fine \r\n and you?\n alone in the dark\n\r\n clean me \n\r kill me'`

`[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 21), match=' Hello how are you'>,
...`

instead of:

`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 21), match='"\r\n" Hello how are you'>,`
`...`

Comment: Ok, I did not handle the cases when your line starts with `"`. Updated

Comment: Thanks @Faibbus, we will be using your solution!